# Manifest file created via manifestclasspath ant task truncating name of jars in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: ant, classpath, manifest

Looked at and followed : [Ant - how to get all files' name in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796824/ant-how-to-get-all-files-name-in-a-specific-folder/3797767#3797767)

But I see jar names are either truncated or jumbled incorrectly in `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Is there a way to fix it?

Here is excerpt of Ant target where I am seeing issue using manifestclasspath or with pathconvert approach..

```
       <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${dist.dir}/Cling.ear">
          <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
          </classpath>
        </manifestclasspath>

      <echo message="${jar.classpath}"/>

      <ear destfile="${dist.dir}/Cling.ear" appxml="${app.home}/WebContent/META-INF/application.xml" manifestencoding="UTF-8">
         <fileset dir="${dist.dir}" includes="**" />
         <manifest>
           <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Some Company" />
           <attribute name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
           <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
         </manifest>
     </ear>
```

Excerpt of that created section looks like below, where you can notice 2 jar names are truncated by some line size or some means & is continued on next line - which results in class not found exception when application is run..

`Class-Path: lib/abcd-efg-1.2.11.jar lib/zzz.jar *lib/abc.def.gh.ijk.l
 mno_8.5.0.jar* lib/com.abc.de.fig_8.5.0.jar *lib/com.blah.zz
 2.some.jar*`

Comment: And I don't see any problem when I print & see output of converted property, were space is correctly present & no jar names are broken into pieces.. `<echo message="${jar.classpath}"/>`

Comment: Hope we can use `manifest` task even for creating Ear?. Official doc shows example on jar creation. ..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758244/add-classpath-in-manifest-file-of-jar-in-gradle-in-java-8?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @martinclayton for the pointer. So you are referring to go with _custom_ ant task to achieve it, as question in above post refer to Gradle?

Comment: No - I think you could just insert newlines before each space in the classpath so that each filename is on its own line, prefixed by a space. (Sorry for the confusing link...)

Comment: As classpath is framed here using fileset includes/** and same is supplied to `manifestclasspath` I am not seeing that as direct option. 

As an alternative tried with `pathconvert` - no luck either

Comment: Here is excerpt of framing that using `pathconvert`


       `<path id="mf.temp.classpath">
              <fileset dir="${path.to.distribute}/lib">
                     <include name="*.jar" />
              </fileset>
       </path>
       

       <pathconvert property="manifest.classpath" pathsep="${line.separator}">
         <path refid="mf.temp.classpath"/>
         <mapper>
           <chainedmapper>
              <flattenmapper/>
              <globmapper from="*.jar" to="lib/*.jar"/>
           </chainedmapper>
         </mapper>
       </pathconvert>`

Comment: They're not truncated or jumbled; they're just newlined. This is how jar manifests are formatted. Fix whatever code is choking on the standard manifest format.

Comment: Actually it's not, with generated Manifest file in that format it results in 'Could not find required class'

Comment: @vinWin Yes, I realize that. That's the problem of whatever program is trying to run it, NOT the manifest file. Go download pretty much any Apache commons jar and look at the manifest. You'll see things are formatted in the same way, with line breaks right in the middle of file names.

Comment: So ideally it is expected to not cause problem with missing class I believe?, but it is resulting in issue. Will double check on that, else I may need to relay on `zip` ant task and explicitly maintaining & packing META-INF/** files..